# How to run Airflow tasks synchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, airflow, amazon-athena

I have an airflow comprising of 2-3 steps

1. PythonOperator --> It runs the query on AWS Athena and stores the generated file on specific s3 path
2. BashOperator --> Increments the airflow variable for tracking
3. BashOperator --> It takes the output(response) of task1 and and run some code on top of it.

What happens here is the airflow gets completed within seconds even if the Athena query step is running.

I want to make sure that after the file is generated further steps should run. Basically i want this to be synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tasks as:

```
def athena_task():
    # Add your code
    return

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='athena_task',
    python_callable=athena_task,
)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='variable_task',
    bash_command='', #replace with relevant command
)

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='process_task',
    bash_command='', #replace with relevant command
)

t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

t2 will run only after t1 is completed successfully and t3 will start only after t2 is completed successfully.

Note that Airflow has [AWSAthenaOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1960e37952efc08ad33328ff511a846f2376ad4f/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/athena.py#L31) which might save you the trouble of writing the code yourself. The operator submit a query to Athena and save the output in S3 path by setting the `output_location` parameter:

```
run_query = AWSAthenaOperator(
    task_id='athena_task',
    query='SELECT * FROM  my_table',
    output_location='s3://some-bucket/some-path/',
    database='my_database'
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Elad. I am doing the same t1 >> t2 >> t3 but on UI it shows that the tasks are success even if the file is not yet generated at the defined location.

One more this is there any way that i can give the name to the csv file generated? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That is really depended on what you do on the `PythonOperator` I assume that in your case you are submitting the request to Athena to run the query and generate the file but you don't wait for the file to be created. This is also why I suggested you to use the `AWSAthenaOperator` because it handles this for you. When you specify `output_location='s3://some-bucket/some-path/'` you can access the path in downstream tasks by : `'s3://some-bucket//some-path/{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids="athena_task") }}.csv'` because the query_execution_id is pushed to xcom

Answer (score 1):

Athena's query API is asynchronous. You start a query, get an ID back, and then you need to poll until the query has completed using the `GetQueryExecution` API call.

If you only start the query in the first task then there is not guarantee that the query has completed when the next task runs. Only when `GetQueryExecution` has returned a status of `SUCCEEDED` (or `FAILED`/`CANCELLED`) can you expect the output file to exist.

As @Elad points out, `AWSAthenaOperator` does this for you, and handles error cases, and more.